ArcMap does not sort numbers of <1 correctly in unique values symbology
I have an issue in ArcMap when working with values that are lower than 1. In the symbology dialogue, when I go to unique values and choose all values for an attribute that has some values of <1, these values are not sorted correctly, but are mixed up with higher and lower numbers in no apparent order, as seen in the image below.

Once the values are higher than 1, they are sorted correctly, also with respect to the decimals. The data I am working on is average rainfall for a number of hydrological catchments.
Has anyone else experienced this? Is there a way to fix it? I am working in version 10.7.1.

Could you please edit your question and add information about the type of data (maybe include a sample dataset), and screenshot(s) of the symbology dialogue?

Thanks for your comment, I have added a screenshot and some more information. I am not sure how to include a sample dataset.

You could at least describe your data. What sort of dataset, shapefile, fgdb, Enterprise geodatabase. What is the exact field type? It looks like a floating point field, so are you sure you want a unique value classification?

I can't reproduce this behavior, all values are sorted correctly for me. Clicking on the Label or Value table headings will give you sorting options. What happens if you use those?

Yes, this worked!! Thank you so much!

For completeness sake, here's my comment as an answer: Clicking the Value or Label header, or right clicking anywhere in the list, will open a context menu with sorting options. Reset sorting will sort all values in ascending order.

